# The intersection multiplicity of two coprime polynomials is less or equal than the multiplicity of their product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Are given $H_1,H_2$ coprime polynomial of $K[X,Y]$ with $K$ a algebraic closed field, $P\in\mathbb{P}^2(K)$ a point. Holds that$$\mu_P(H_1,H_2)\leq m_P(H_1H_2)$$ where $\mu$ is the intersection multiplicity and $m$ the multiplicity?

It's a small part of a big exercise, if I solve this I'm done, but can't see how. I think it's true because I can't think of a controexamples, and intuitively it make sens.

PS:I can't bring what I tried, because I was able to prove that everything that I tried wouldn't bring to a solution.

PPS: Sorry for my bad English.

EDIT:$\ $Ok, I came up with this: assuming $P=(0,0)$ and given $h_1,h_2 $disomogenizated polynomials of $H_1,H_2$ $$\mu_P(H_1,H_2)=dim\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_1,h_2)}$$ and $$m_P(H_1H_2)=m_P(H_1)+m_P(H_2)=dim\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_1,l_1)}\times\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_2,l_2)}=dim\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_1,l_1)}+dim\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_2,l_2)}$$
Where $l_1,l_2$ are the degree one polynomial that realize the minum in the definition of multiplicity.
Now if I show that exists a injective map $$\phi:\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_1,h_2)}\to\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_1,l_1)}\times\frac{K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}}{(h_2,l_2)}$$ I'm done.

Comment: Think about containment of ideals and how multiplicity works with one ideal contained in another.

Comment: Something on the line $(H_1H_2)\subseteq(H_1)$ and $(H_1,H_2)\subseteq(H_2)$? For have the right start point.